# How to enable AUTODDL on Firebird using .NET Provider?

Tags: c#, firebird, embedded-database

I need to enable AUTODDL in a Firebird embedded database from a C# App. Using isql, it is as simple as executing:

```
SET AUTODDL ON;
```

but I'm not being able to execute that statement with a FbCommand. I'm getting the error:

```
Token unknown - line 1, column 5
AUTODDL
```

Answer (score 1):

AUTOddl isn't a firebird command it's a isql command. [iSql](http://www.destructor.de/firebird/isql.htm)

Have you maybe though about executing the command using the process functoin.

```
public void Execute() {

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Programme\Firebird2\bin\isql.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format( " -q -user {0} -password {1} elias:{2} SET AUTOddl ON", user, password,"Database" );
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

p.Start();
}
```

Please note I havn't tested the above but it should work. If it doesn't you can try and put the sql script in a script file then execute the script file.

Parameters to execute script are as follows.  `-q -i c:\Scripts\CreateScript.sql`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've been using IB Query and it also allows the use of "SET AUTODDL ON". Isn't it possible to use that sentence with a FbCommand?